# How to replace media player with exo player?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I have making an app to play songs which are stored in the phone and also to stream music urls. But android media player is very slow than the exo player. So I want replace the media player in my code with exo player. Could someone please replace the media player in this code with exo player in a suitable way please?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import etwinkle.solutions.musico.service.playback.Playback;
import com.vaktech.musico.R;
import etwinkle.solutions.musico.util.PreferenceUtil;


public class MultiPlayer implements Playback, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    public static final String TAG = MultiPlayer.class.getSimpleName();

    private MediaPlayer mCurrentMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private MediaPlayer mNextMediaPlayer;

    private Context context;
    @Nullable
    private Playback.PlaybackCallbacks callbacks;

    private boolean mIsInitialized = false;

    /**
     * Constructor of <code>MultiPlayer</code>
     */
    public MultiPlayer(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    }

    /**
     * @param path The path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream
     *             you want to play
     * @return True if the <code>player</code> has been prepared and is
     * ready to play, false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean setDataSource(@NonNull final String path) {
        mIsInitialized = false;
        mIsInitialized = setDataSourceImpl(mCurrentMediaPlayer, path);
        if (mIsInitialized) {
            setNextDataSource(null);
        }
        return mIsInitialized;
    }

    /**
     * @param player The {@link MediaPlayer} to use
     * @param path   The path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream
     *               you want to play
     * @return True if the <code>player</code> has been prepared and is
     * ready to play, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean setDataSourceImpl(@NonNull final MediaPlayer player, @NonNull final String path) {
        if (context == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(null);
            if (path.startsWith("content://")) {
                player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(path));
            } else {
                player.setDataSource(path);
            }
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION);
        intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, getAudioSessionId());
        intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_CONTENT_TYPE, AudioEffect.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set the MediaPlayer to start when this MediaPlayer finishes playback.
     *
     * @param path The path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream
     *             you want to play
     */
    @Override
    public void setNextDataSource(@Nullable final String path) {
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Next media player is current one, continuing");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Media player not initialized!");
            return;
        }
        if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
            mNextMediaPlayer.release();
            mNextMediaPlayer = null;
        }
        if (path == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (PreferenceUtil.getInstance(context).gaplessPlayback()) {
            mNextMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mNextMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            mNextMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(getAudioSessionId());
            if (setDataSourceImpl(mNextMediaPlayer, path)) {
                try {
                    mCurrentMediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mNextMediaPlayer);
                } catch (@NonNull IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "setNextDataSource: setNextMediaPlayer()", e);
                    if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
                        mNextMediaPlayer.release();
                        mNextMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mNextMediaPlayer.release();
                    mNextMediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the callbacks
     *
     * @param callbacks The callbacks to use
     */
    @Override
    public void setCallbacks(final Playback.PlaybackCallbacks callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;
    }

    /**
     * @return True if the player is ready to go, false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isInitialized() {
        return mIsInitialized;
    }

    /**
     * Starts or resumes playback.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean start() {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.start();
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state.
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.reset();
        mIsInitialized = false;
    }

    /**
     * Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object.
     */
    @Override
    public void release() {
        stop();
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
        if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
            mNextMediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pauses playback. Call start() to resume.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean pause() {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.pause();
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the MultiPlayer is playing.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mIsInitialized && mCurrentMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the duration of the file.
     *
     * @return The duration in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public int duration() {
        if (!mIsInitialized) {
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            return mCurrentMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current playback position.
     *
     * @return The current position in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public int position() {
        if (!mIsInitialized) {
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            return mCurrentMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current playback position.
     *
     * @param whereto The offset in milliseconds from the start to seek to
     * @return The offset in milliseconds from the start to seek to
     */
    @Override
    public int seek(final int whereto) {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.seekTo(whereto);
            return whereto;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setVolume(final float vol) {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.setVolume(vol, vol);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the audio session ID.
     *
     * @param sessionId The audio session ID
     */
    @Override
    public boolean setAudioSessionId(final int sessionId) {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(sessionId);
            return true;
        } catch (@NonNull IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the audio session ID.
     *
     * @return The current audio session ID.
     */
    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return mCurrentMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onError(final MediaPlayer mp, final int what, final int extra) {
        mIsInitialized = false;
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
        mCurrentMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        if (context != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.unplayable_file), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mp == mCurrentMediaPlayer && mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
            mIsInitialized = false;
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
            mCurrentMediaPlayer = mNextMediaPlayer;
            mIsInitialized = true;
            mNextMediaPlayer = null;
            if (callbacks != null)
                callbacks.onTrackWentToNext();
        } else {
            if (callbacks != null)
                callbacks.onTrackEnded();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I made. But it is not working. Here I call setDatSourceImpl() first then start(). But the song is not being streamed.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.vaktech.musico.R;

import etwinkle.solutions.musico.service.MultiPlayer;
import etwinkle.solutions.musico.service.playback.Playback;
import etwinkle.solutions.musico.util.PreferenceUtil;

/**
 * Created by hasitha on 1/10/18.
 */

public class MultiPlayer  implements Playback{
    public static final String TAG = MultiPlayer.class.getSimpleName();

    private SimpleExoPlayer mCurrentMediaPlayer;
    private SimpleExoPlayer mNextMediaPlayer;
    private BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    private ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory;
    private TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory;
    private TrackSelector trackSelector;
    private DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter;
    private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
    private MediaSource mediaSource;

    private Context context;
    @Nullable
    private Playback.PlaybackCallbacks callbacks;

    private boolean mIsInitialized = false;

    /**
     * Constructor of <code>MultiPlayer</code>
     */
    public MultiPlayer(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mCurrentMediaPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                new DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);

        defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "mediaPlayerSample"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
    }

    /**
     * @param path The path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream
     *             you want to play
     * @return True if the <code>player</code> has been prepared and is
     * ready to play, false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean setDataSource(@NonNull final String path) {
        mIsInitialized = false;
        mIsInitialized = setDataSourceImpl(mCurrentMediaPlayer, path);
        if (mIsInitialized) {
            setNextDataSource(null);
        }
        return mIsInitialized;
    }

    /**
     * @param player The {@link MediaPlayer} to use
     * @param path   The path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream
     *               you want to play
     * @return True if the <code>player</code> has been prepared and is
     * ready to play, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean setDataSourceImpl(@NonNull ExoPlayer player, @NonNull final String path) {
        if (context == null) {
            return false;
        }


        try{
            mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(path), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException in) {
            mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(path), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        }
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        Log.d("Exceptions","Here he is ready");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION);
        intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, getAudioSessionId());
        intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_CONTENT_TYPE, AudioEffect.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set the MediaPlayer to start when this MediaPlayer finishes playback.
     *
     * @param path The path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream
     *             you want to play
     */

    @Override
    public void setNextDataSource(@Nullable final String path) {
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            //mCurrentMediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Next media player is current one, continuing");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Media player not initialized!");
            return;
        }
        if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
            mNextMediaPlayer.release();
            mNextMediaPlayer = null;
        }
        if (path == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (PreferenceUtil.getInstance(context).gaplessPlayback()) {
            /*
            mNextMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mNextMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            mNextMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(getAudioSessionId());
            if (setDataSourceImpl(mNextMediaPlayer, path)) {
                try {
                    mCurrentMediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mNextMediaPlayer);
                } catch (@NonNull IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "setNextDataSource: setNextMediaPlayer()", e);
                    if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
                        mNextMediaPlayer.release();
                        mNextMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mNextMediaPlayer.release();
                    mNextMediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        */
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the callbacks
     *
     * @param callbacks The callbacks to use
     */
    @Override
    public void setCallbacks(final Playback.PlaybackCallbacks callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;
    }

    /**
     * @return True if the player is ready to go, false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isInitialized() {
        return mIsInitialized;
    }

    /**
     * Starts or resumes playback.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean start() {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            Log.d("Exceptions","Here Legal");
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("Exceptions","Here Illegal");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state.
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
        mIsInitialized = false;
        Log.d("Exceptions","Here stop please");
    }

    /**
     * Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object.
     */
    @Override
    public void release() {
        //stop();
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
        if (mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
            mNextMediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pauses playback. Call start() to resume.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean pause() {
        Log.d("Exceptions","Here pause please");
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the MultiPlayer is playing.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mIsInitialized && mCurrentMediaPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the duration of the file.
     *
     * @return The duration in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public int duration() {
        if (!mIsInitialized) {
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            long l = mCurrentMediaPlayer.getDuration();
            return (int) l;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current playback position.
     *
     * @return The current position in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public int position() {
        if (!mIsInitialized) {
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            long l = mCurrentMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            return (int) l;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current playback position.
     *
     * @param whereto The offset in milliseconds from the start to seek to
     * @return The offset in milliseconds from the start to seek to
     */
    @Override
    public int seek(final int whereto) {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.seekTo(whereto);
            return whereto;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setVolume(final float vol) {
        try {
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.setVolume(vol);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the audio session ID.
     *
     * @param sessionId The audio session ID
     */
    @Override
    public boolean setAudioSessionId(final int sessionId) {
        try {
            //mCurrentMediaPlayer.setA(sessionId);
            return true;
        } catch (@NonNull IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the audio session ID.
     *
     * @return The current audio session ID.
     */
    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return mCurrentMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onError(final SimpleExoPlayer mp, final int what, final int extra) {
        mIsInitialized = false;
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
        mCurrentMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mCurrentMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        if (context != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.unplayable_file), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    /*
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mp == mCurrentMediaPlayer && mNextMediaPlayer != null) {
            mIsInitialized = false;
            mCurrentMediaPlayer.release();
            mCurrentMediaPlayer = mNextMediaPlayer;
            mIsInitialized = true;
            mNextMediaPlayer = null;
            if (callbacks != null)
                callbacks.onTrackWentToNext();
        } else {
            if (callbacks != null)
                callbacks.onTrackEnded();
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you take a crack at it yourself and then post a question on any particular issues you run into. [The documentation](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) plus the [demo app](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java) should be enough to answer your question.

Comment: Or you can use a library like [this one](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia), but I'd suggest making your own implementation to get the full use out of ExoPlayer.

Comment: @KyleVenn I added an answer. please review that. still that is not working

Comment: Okay great! I'm glad you put some code to get started. When I have some free time I'll take another look at it. One thing I can think of that you might want to change is instead of using "nextMediaPlayer" you might want to use the same instance of exoplayer and use a playlist/the ConcatenatingMediaSource.

Comment: thank you. I can do that but don't care that. It is not playing even one song.

Comment: @Hasitha did you replace the media player or you rewrite the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

It's late but it may help others. You are missing event listener in your exoplayer.

```
 private ExoPlayer.EventListener eventListener = new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {


    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onTracksChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLoadingChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: playWhenReady = " + String.valueOf(playWhenReady)
                + " playbackState = " + playbackState);
        switch (playbackState) {
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Playback ended!");
                //Stop playback and return to start position
                setPlayPause(false);
                mExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
                if(callbacks!=null)
                    callbacks.onTrackEnded();

                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                Log.i(TAG, "ExoPlayer ready! pos: " + mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition()
                        + " max: " + stringForTime((int) mExoPlayer.getDuration())+ " isPlaying");

                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:

                Log.i(TAG, "Playback buffering!");
                break;
            case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "ExoPlayer idle!");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPlaybackError: " + error.getMessage());
    }


};

private void setPlayPause(boolean play) {

    mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(play);

}
```

and then give this listener to your exoplayer in the constructor like this.

```
MultiPlayer(final Context context) {
    .
    .
    mExoPlayer.addListener(eventListener);
    .
    .
 }
```